# Is there a way to catch request side network exception in java?

Tags: java, http, request

I am using [Request](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/fluent.html) class in org.apache.http.client.fluent to post some data from one webserver to another webserver. When a network failure occurs, I want to know if the network error happened when posting the data or when waiting for a response from the server. If I catch `java.net.SocketException`, it catches all network exceptions. Is there a sub class that catches only request side network exceptions?

pseudo code for what I am trying to do

```
try
{
  Request.Post(address);
}
catch(RequestNetworkException ex)
{
  //come here only if the network error happens before data reaches the server
  doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. Can an exception occur *after* the post has reached the server? Isn't the whole `Post` method finished then?

Comment: Yes. Once the post data reaches the server, the controller that receives this request, executes some code and then returns a response code and maybe even some data, like the id of the newly created record. While the receiving controller is executing code, the connection between the two webservers can get severed.

Comment: Oh, of course. I see. Good question.